# ¿Cómo elevar al cuadrado un float?

Tags: c#

Tengo el siguiente problema:
Necesito hallar el área de un circulo dependiendo del número que el usuario digite; el problema está en que no se como elevar al cuadrado un float, aquí el código:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    float pi = 3.14159f;
    float radio = 0.0f;
    float area = 0f;

    radio = float.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
    area = pi * radio * radio;
    Console.WriteLine("A=" + area + "\r\n");
}
```

Si observan algunos errores para poder correr mi programa como quiero no duden en avisar, estaré al tanto. Muchas gracias de antemano!

Comment: ¿Por qué no funciona radio * radio? ¿Qué resultado esperas?

Comment: Hola amigo gracias por el comentario; necesito que cuando el ususario introduzca un numero, ej. ("2.00") el resultado sea: ("12.5664") y no ("12.56636") Que redondee el resultado después del punto

Comment: Podrías usar [Math.pow](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/api/system.math.pow?view=netcore-3.1). Sin embargo toma en cuenta que dicho método espera argumentos de tipo `double` y el valor devuelto también será de tipo `double`. Si no deseas usar `double`, la forma en que lo estás haciendo es suficiente. Saludos

Answer (score 2):

Podrías utilizar [Math.Round](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.math.round?view=netcore-3.1)

Ya que mencionas esto en un comentario:

```
"ej. ("2.00") el resultado sea: ("12.5664") y no ("12.56636")"
```

En tu caso podrías redondear area a 4 digitos

```
 Math.Round((float)area, 4, MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero)
```

Aquí el ejemplo completo

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{

float pi = 3.14159f;
float radio = 0.0f;
float area = 0f;
radio = float.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

area = pi * radio * radio;
Console.WriteLine("A=" + area + "\r\n");     

Console.WriteLine("A=" + Math.Round((float)area, 4, MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero) + "\r\n");
Console.Read();
}
```

}

Salida:

[image: Salida]